# Console.Writeline(integer); prints number without decimals even though there should be decimals

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to print out this integer variable which in the case of my test numbers should be 5,2333 but only 5 gets printed.

int finalTimeInt = ((N * 60 + n) / 2) / 60;
Console.Writeline(finalTimeInt);

As stated already I'm expecting an output of 5,2333 but am only getting a 5.

Comment: [What is an integer number](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)

Answer (score 0):

Integers can't hold decimals. If you want a variable to store decimals, you should be using a floating-point type, like `float`, or `double` if you want more accuracy.

Comment: how would I go about doing this? I'm quite new to C#

Comment: instead of `int finalTimeInt = ((N * 60 + n) / 2) / 60` you should have `float finalTimeInt = ((N * 60 + n) / 2) / 60`

Comment: Ok, I've tried that now but I'm still not getting an output with decimals.

edit: I've fixed it, I changed the other variables to be float variables aswell and now it works, thanks!